# C# Obfuscation and XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, obfuscation

I have a button in a xaml file that should be hidden in some cases.

Here it is:

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowMyButton}"/>
```

The binding works perfect until it comes to obfuscating my code.

In the AssemblyInfo.cs I added the following assembly annotation:

```
[assembly: ObfuscateAssemblyAttribute(false, StripAfterObfuscation = false)]
```

By the way, I use Eazfuscator.NET

After obfuscating the code the button is always visible, i.e. the bind does not work anymore.

I added the following annotation to the ShowMyButton property:

```
[ObfuscationAttribute(Exclude=true)]
public bool ShowMyButton
{
     get
     {
         return _showMe;
     }
     set
     {
         _showMe= value;
         OnPropertyChanged("ShowMyButton");
     }
}
```

This exclusion works fine, but I have 3 questions:

1. why the xaml got confused when it comes to obfuscation. can I tell the obfuscator not to obfuscate methods that refer to binding in xaml files?
2. According to msdn ObfuscateAssemblyAttribute distincts only between public and private methods. It would be very frustrating to manually exclude all methods that refer to binding in the xaml files (There are dozens in my application). Is there an automatic option?
3. Is there a way to tell the obfucator to obfuscate only specific method in the application, i.e. please do not obfuscate anything by default until i tell you to do so.

Comment: my personal opinion, use dotfuscator; it works really well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue and [it was fixed](http://blog.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net/xaml-renaming-for-wpf) in recent versions of Eazfuscator.NET.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is nothing to do with XAML. The issue is in your implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`; highlighting why stringly-typed is a bad idea. The obfuscator is renaming `ShowMyButton` everywhere it is used as a method, but it does not rename the occurrence of the string in:

```
OnPropertyChanged("ShowMyButton");
```

After obfuscation, the update events that are fired will say that the property "ShowMyButton" has been updated, yet the actual property has been renamed to an obfuscated value, so any code relying on this interface, including XAML's data binding will not update correctly, always showing the default value of a boolean: true.

A more refactor friendly implementation uses expressions rather than string typing, thus the offending line could be rewritten to

```
OnPropertyChanged(() => this.ShowMyButton);
```

[One possible implementation of this pattern.](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/257473/Make-OnPropertyChanged-events-safe-for-refactoring)

Comment: The change works fine on non-obfuscated code. When when it comes to obfuscated code it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Try Babel for .net  and check it out at http://babelfor.net/
It has very good obfuscation for XAML.
Note also that Eazfuscator is easily deobfuscated by a combination of
de4dot and ILSpy. And its renaming of variables and values are very
simple which ILSpy can reveal all.

Babel on the other hand, add in loops, iterations, switches which
can confuse the crackers and make any deobfuscated code unreadable
and untraceable. It also can encrypt strings and entire methods 
making them unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

If the obfuscator obfuscates the `ShowMyButton` property, but doesn't rename it in the compiled XAML, the binding doesn't have a target, as it still targets `ShowMyButton`, not the obfuscated version.